# Forward a complete conversation/thread in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I have a long chain of 20+ emails in Gmail I wish to forward to someone else. I don't want to forward them individually.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 15):

In the latest GMail, you can do this via the "More" menu, if you have the conversation selected:

[image: Gmail more, Forward All]

Click `More`, then click `Forward All`. This results in a new email sent to whomever you choose with all the emails in the conversation / thread in a single email that looks like this:

> #### Forwarded conversation
>
> Subject: **Subject**
>
> ---
>
> (all the emails in the conversation / thread will be included in the body here as one giant email)

And this forward itself ends up being part of the original conversation, so I don't know what happens if you forward a conversation twice. :)

Comment: I could not find the "Forward all" feature in new GMail.  My "More" menu has 6 options: (all as shown in screenshot above, except does not have Create Event, does not have Forward all).

Comment: @bobobobo it will not be on the main screen, rather when u open the mail you can see it on the top.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of GMail, as of 7/22/13, hitting the Forward button does "Forward All" by default.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, Forward All is no longer in the hamburger menu; it's now (2017) the small right-pointing black arrow on the right side of the subject line, above the first email in the thread.