# How can I forward an entire conversation and retain attachments in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, email, email-forwarding, gmail-conversations

As stated in the title, I want to forward an entire conversation (as asked in [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33157/forward-a-complete-conversation-thread-in-gmail), although the method to do this has changed a bit due to UI changes) while retaining all the attachments in the conversation so that the recipient of the forwarded conversation gets the attachments as well.

Is this possible? I tested forwarding the whole conversation but all attachments are removed when sent. Only forwarding the individual message to which a file has been attached actually sends the attachment, but that also means the recipient cannot read the rest of the conversation.

Answer (score 2):

There is an icon "Forward All" in Gmail which can achieve this:-

[image: Forward All]

Needless to say, this option is only visible when a conversation has more than 1 email.

However, this clubs all the attachments of different emails within the conversation together as essentially you are the one sending a single email, so you may need to mention who sent what attachment while forwarding it.